# Unable to find column with logical name finc_mdse_model_desgtr

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, foreign-keys, spring-data-jpa

Looks like this is popular question but I cant still figure out why

Working with spring boot 2.0.3, jpa, hibernate, teradata

I was able to generate pojo from database. I am working with Views and not Tables if that matters. So these are read-only for me.

Intellij has auto-complete, so it validates annotation values for me. They all seem to be correct. There is really FINC_MDSE_MODEL_DESGTR in fs_veh_ident

Main table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FS_VEH_IDENT", schema = "VEHICLE360", catalog = "")
public class VehicleIdentity {
@Id
private String vehIdNbr;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicle", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<VehicleOption> vehicleOptions;

private String subVin;
private String squishVin;
private String vinModelYrNbr;
private String vinModlYrCd;
```

...

Options table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FS_VEH_OPTION_CFD", schema = "VEHICLE360", catalog = "")
public class VehicleOption {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "MDNSG_MODEL_DESGTR", referencedColumnName = "FINC_MDSE_MODEL_DESGTR", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private VehicleIdentity vehicle;

private String ctryCd;
private String langCd;
private String modelYrNbr;
private String gsmcMake;
private String gsmcModel;

@Id
private String mdnsgModelDesgtr;
private String optionCd;
```

...

Error says

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: FINC_MDSE_MODEL_DESGTR in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(vehicle360.fs_veh_ident) and its related supertables and secondary tables
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:832)
at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:244)
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:101)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1771)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1715)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1602)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
```

Pure sql

```
select option_cd as optioncode, 
        opt.consumer_ctgry_desc as categorydescription, 

        from vehicle360.fs_veh_option_cfd as opt 
        left join vehicle360.fs_veh_ident vi on opt.mdnsg_model_desgtr = vi.finc_mdse_model_desgtr 
        where vi.veh_id_nbr = :vin2
```

**Edit 1:**

Looks like I have hit some kind of bug with hibernate 5.2.17 - I saw that some method was trying to map logical name to physical inside hibernate, I changed referencedColumnName to fincMdseModelDesgtr (camel case) and the damn thing works!!

Comment: make your edit an answer (and accept it). Makes the answer easier to find and also obvious that this question doesn't need another one.

Comment: i will, let me figure out if this works in another versions of hibernate or if I am doing anything wrong